Is there an antonym for 'euphemism', that is to say - the replacing of a sacred word with a commonplace word?
A euphemism is a word that is substituted for another word that is offensive or vulgar. What about in the opposite direction? What do you call a word that is substituted for another word that is too holy to pronounce? Like we Jews never say the tetragrammaton. We use substitutes like "Adonai". And I suspect that the Hebrew words "hamah" for Sun and "levnah" for Moon were invented by pagans who worshipped the Sun and Moon as substitutes for "shemesh" for Sun and "Yareah" for Moon.

It doesn't have to be offensive of vulgar. It's for any word where it's offensive or uncomfortable to use the original word. E.g. "downsizing" is a euphemism for layoffs, and "gosh" is a euphemism for "God".

So all your examples are euphemisms.

The words you cannot say might be regarded as taboo for whatever reason.    Their replacements are definitely euphemisms but substitutions might be an alternative if you prefer.

@Lambie Catholic Bibles don't contain the Tetragrammaton.

Just read several Wikipedia articles like Names of God in Judaism, Naming taboo, Thou shalt not take the name of the Lord thy God in vain, Avoidance speech, etc, and can't see a specific term - just substitute etc. I guess such taboos are so culturally omnipresent they don't need a name (God's name is unlikely to change, but in imperial China where it was forbidden to use syllables of the emperor's name, it's not even clear how people were told what to avoid, but there are examples e.g. of Korean ambassadors requesting a list of taboo syllables and getting given one.)

@AndrewLeach But it is because the Catholic bishops consider it like this: "The letter from the Holy See explains that the Divine Name as revealed in the Old Testament, יהוה (YHWH), has been held as unpronounceable as an expression of reverence for the greatness of God". Because of having to put in vowels, not because it is taboo. https://www.usccb.org/prayer-and-worship/the-mass/frequently-asked-questions/the-name-of-god-in-the-liturgy

@Lambie You're wrong. From your own source, it's an expression of reverence and "from the beginning… the sacred tetragrammaton was never pronounced in the Christian context nor translated into any languages into which the Bible was translated."

@AndrewLeach Some Bible versions, such as the Jerusalem Bible, employ the name Yahweh, a transliteration of the Hebrew tetragrammaton (YHWH), in the English text of the Old Testament, where traditional English versions have LORD.[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_Name_Bible

@Lambie And that doesn't negate my comment about Catholic bibles. It's actually forbidden by the Church.

Euphemism includes when a taboo but not vulgar term is replaced by a more palatable term, as is the case in religious contexts like yours. According to the euphemism entry in An Encyclopedia of Swearing by Geoffrey Hughes:

Articulating the name of God is completely taboo in many religions, such as Islam and Judaism, generating coded forms like JWH. Historically, it provides the longest continuous example of euphemism in English, from forms like gog and cokk in the fourteenth century, followed by several dozen variants. Around 1600 a number of apostrophized forms like zounds for “God’s wounds” and ’sblood for “God’s blood” sprang into prominence, as a response to injunctions against the use of the name of God on the stage. These are called minced oaths. Secular examples are blooming and plain b for bloody, and the euphemistic variants of pissed off—namely, peed off, teed off, and kissed off.

Strictly speaking, the opposite of a euphemism is when one term is replaced by a less palatable term, or dysphemism. Many terms have both: "passed away" is a euphemism for "died" while "pushing up daisies" is a dysphemism.
